# How should this confidence interval be understood?

Tags: confidence-interval, interpretation, medicine

In a recent article called [Association of Childhood Growth Hormone Treatment With Long-term Cardiovascular Morbidity](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapediatrics/article-abstract/2773797) (behind a paywall, unfortunately), the authors conclude

> In this cohort study, treatment with rhGH during childhood due to GHD, SGA, or ISS was associated with increased risks of cardiovascular events in early adulthood, particularly in women; however, conclusions of causality are still limited and the absolute risk remains low.

The increased risk seems to be measured by these incidence rates:

[image]

The "incidence rate" is defined as the number of cardiac events per 10,000 person years.

I'm trying to understand how strong is the conclusion that males are at elevated risk. Taking only the breakdown for males, the findings are that there were 23.3 events per 10,000 person year in the patient group, but only 22.3 in the control group. The confidence interval of that control group is big enough that it includes the actual measured patient rate, and vice versa (which is not true of the CI's of the female group).

Given these numbers, how strongly could we conclude that--for males only--there is in fact an elevated risk?

Comment: The cited conclusion of the authors is not based on table 2 in the screenshot but on table 3 which contains the result of adjusted Cox models and the corresponding hazard ratios. You could compute the crude incidence rate ratios which are $1.05$ (95%-CI: $0.83;\;1.31$) for men and $1.34$ (95%-CI: $0.97;\;1.81$) for women. These correspond roughly to the crude hazard ratios in table 3. But the authors adjusted the models for potential confounders and based their conclusions on these.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: Thanks for going to the source paper and orienting me on this. So now I understand where to look, but I'm still unclear about the strength of the conclusion. The crude hazard ratio for males is 1.05 (which is only slightly more than 1.0, which would be no elevated risk at all), and the CI on that in fact ranges well below 1.0. But then the adjusted models boost this quite a bit, to 1.55. What is the right way to interpret that HR number? Does it mean that we would expect 1.55 times as many cardiac events in the patient population vs the control population in some time period?

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking how to interpret a hazard ratio in general. The hazard ratio is the ratio of two hazard rates. Concretely, the hazard ratio of $1.55$ in this case would mean that the patients had a hazard rate for CV events that was $1.55$ times higher compared to controls. For a fixed time frame and comparable subjects, we'd expect $1.55$ times as many events in patients compared to controls, on average.